# What to do when cdk bootstrap does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have created a simple stack to deploy with cdk, to make things simple I followed the aws example, creating an s3 bucket using the cdk with typescript language.
These are my dependencies:

```
      "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.10",
    "@types/node": "10.17.27",
    "aws-cdk": "2.19.0",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.19.0",
    "constructs": "^10.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  }
```

When doing cdk deploy, the following error message comes up:

```
✨  Synthesis time: 7.82s

AwsLab2Stack: deploying...
[0%] start: Publishing 7acebacf84a3ee9c1a08331d943a313131c77ec0f49614e1b7eb0a7c37362d71:040831115250-us-west-2
[100%] fail: No bucket named 'cdk-hnb659fds-assets-XXXXXXXXX-us-west-2'. Is account XXXXXXXXX bootstrapped?

 ❌  AwsLab2Stack failed: Error: Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
    at publishAssets (C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\util\asset-publishing.ts:28:11)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.publishStackAssets (C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\api\cloudformation-deployments.ts:418:7)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.deployStack (C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\api\cloudformation-deployments.ts:299:5)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\cdk-toolkit.ts:208:24)
    at initCommandLine (C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\cli.ts:312:12)

Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
```

I have done `cdk bootstrap` already, can't figure out what is wrong here.
My cdk version: 2.19.0

When running cdk bootstrap for the specific account and region:

```
⏳  Bootstrapping environment 123456789/us-west-2...
Trusted accounts for deployment: (none)
Trusted accounts for lookup: (none)
Using default execution policy of 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess'. Pass '--cloudformation-execution-policies' to customize.
 ✅  Environment 123456789/us-west-2 bootstrapped (no changes).
```

But then when excuting `cdk deploy` the same error comes.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you run the bootstrapping in us-west-2? Try running `cdk bootstrap aws://123456789012/us-west-2` again.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but it still remains the same, I edit the post to add what happens when doing the cdk bootstrap command.

Comment: Are you deploying cross account ? (usual setup in pipelines )

Maybe the bootstrap is in "provisioning" account but was not executed in the target account ?

Was the Bootstrap stack successful ? 

I don't think that the error is in cdk, but that the bootstrap was not successfully executed on your target account :/

Answer (score 8):

After deleting the current `CDKToolkit` stack in cloudformation and retry it went well.